# retrieving firebase database value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

[screenshot of  database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV3OQ.png)

```
   Auth.$onAuthStateChanged(function(authUser){
  if(authUser){
    console.log(authUser);
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("users");
    console.log("ref::" +ref);
    //var rec = $firebaseArray(ref);
    var usersRe= ref + "/" + authUser.uid + authUser.$id;
    console.log(usersRe);
    var userObj=$firebaseObject(usersRe);
    $scope.currentUser=userObj;
  }else{
    $scope.currentUser='';
  }
});
```

**https://loginsystem-1ab0d.firebaseio.com/users/avL76HGunuYTG2fR3uO3OEblXZ33/**
  enable to get the child of userId(avL76HGunuYTG2fR3uO3OEblXZ33) which is the 
  key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a slash and not using ref correctly. You don't append strings onto the ref, you would do a `.child(...)`

```
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref()
    .child("users")
    .child(authUser.uid + '/' + authUser.$id)
```

Comment: same error after adding slash.
I think its some kind of function to get the key. but can't find that function.